# ESLint error when importing .sass file into React component

Tags: javascript, sass, eslint

I'm importing `.sass` styles into my `.jsx` component and getting this `defined but never used` error from ESLint(Airbnb preset). How can I suppress that error?

Comment: `//eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars`

Comment: Thanks for option, but is there a way to disable only for styles-imports?

Comment: "is there a way to disable only for styles-imports" I doubt that. Could you add your code? If you don't use styles in your code you could just import it (for side effects) w/o defining a local variable `import './path/to/stylesheet.sass'`

Comment: Removing local variable solved the issue.Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Converted to an answer format for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress this warning for a line of code you could use

```
 //eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
 //eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
```

Or you could import module w/o binding [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
import './path/to/styles.sass' // for side-effects only
```